# Hash Tables: why doesn't this code resolve collisions?

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap, hashtable, hash-collision

This insert function doesn't seem to insert correctly and overwrites previous entries. Also the duplicate check doesn't work as intended and only works half the time.

```
HT::HT(const unsigned& tblSize) {

  //Hash table size equal to size passed or default size TBL_SIZE
  hsize = tblSize;
  //Pointer table defualt 0
  psize = 0;

  //reisze tables
  hTable.resize(hsize);
  pTable.resize(hsize);

  //set unused values to empty($$$)
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < hsize; i++)
    hTable[i].key = FREE;
}


//implementation of insert function
void HT::insert(const Entry& record) {

  //assign integer value to index via hash function
  int index = (hash(record.key) % 31);

  //logic to insert into hash table
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < hsize; i++) {
    //inserting into table with linear probing collision resolution

    //inserting into hash table with linear probing as collision resolution
    if (hTable[(index+i)%hsize].key == FREE) {

      hTable[index] = record;
      pTable[psize] = &hTable[(index+i)%hsize];
      psize++;
      cout << " Entry = " << ((index+i)%hsize) << endl;

      return;
    }

    //Duplicate key check
    else if (hTable[(index+i)%hsize].key == record.key) {
      cout << " Entry = Not Inserted - Duplicate key!! " << endl; return;
    }

    //Capacity of table check
    else if (i == hsize - 1) {
      cout << " Not Inserted -  Table full!! " << endl; return;
    }

  } //end for loop
}
```

It seems to insert fine and the duplicate key check works on one data set but not the other with more data values that fill the table to TBL_SIZE = 31. Also the FREE constant sets all vector values to $$$ to designate a free spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//inserting into hash table with linear probing as collision resolution
if (hTable[(index+i)%hsize].key == FREE) {

  hTable[index] = record;
```

You don't want to insert into [index] when [(index + i)%hsize] is the free location.

Comment: That is a nice catch!